# Can't get COUNT result from sqli query

Tags: php, sql, count

When I run this code it only ever returns 0, even when I have the right information. I have checked in the database the same query and it returns a count of one when I have the correct info but this always returns 0.

```
$query = 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM user WHERE UserName = "$username"  AND UserPass = "$password"';

    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);

    $hello = mysqli_fetch_array($result); echo $hello[0]; exit;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change to

```
 $query = 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM user WHERE UserName = "' . $username . '" AND UserPass = "'. $password .'"';
```

Answer (score 0):

I really hope you left out your extensive security measures from your snippet. I suggest you apply some prepared statements pronto, but that's a different question!

Instead of using a `fetch`, try using `num_rows`.

```
$query = "SELECT 1 FROM `user` WHERE `UserName` = '$username'  AND `UserPass` = '$password'";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
echo mysqli_num_rows($result);
```

Try and play around with something like that!

Comment: Hey, havent written those yet. what sort of stuff should i be looking at security wise? this isnt an expensive login system so nothing industrial haha

Comment: Good question! Even if your system is for a couple friends, things can still go wrong with just adding values to the SQL. I suggest Googling `mysqli_real_escape_string` or taking a look at [prepared statements](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Also, StackOverflow has [a page about security](http://security.stackexchange.com/) you can check out!